# I want to open a file which is present in my D directory by clicking on the link bio data?

Tags: html, eclipse, jsp, file-upload

```
 <%  
  out.print("<a  href='file:///D:\\helloitext1.pdf'>"+"BIO DATA"+"</a>");
 %>
```

I have a file name helloitext1.pdf  in D drive  and i want that when click on
 the link bio data my file gets open  i know i am lacking somewhere.
 Tools which I am using are Eclipse  and apache tomcat(localhost).
 The file get open when i have paste the file in eclipse directory  but i 
 want to open the file by clicking on the link Bio data from my D drive .
 Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: give the complete path of ur file. D:/path-to-file/file.pdf

Comment: I have given complete path but I am running this program on localhost and my file is present in D:/helloitext1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

To Access Local Files or Static Content (Images, Videos, Media or any other files outside of the Web Application(WAR)) in the System.

Go to  TOMCAT_DIRECTORY/conf/server.xml and Add the following content in server.xml

```
<Context docBase=”D:/foldername/” path=”/files” />
```

Add all the files you want to access in this folder. Use path ="files/helloitext1.pdf"

[Refer this](http://teknosrc.com/access-local-files-static-content-images-videos-media-files-outside-web-application-system-apache-tomcat-server/)